# Edmodo Image Cropper Android no correct switching from landscape to portrait

Tags: android, image, crop

Hello i am Using the Edmodo Cropper Library and got some Problem with the Layout if switching between portrait and landscape. From landscape everything looks fine (See first 2 Pics).

[image: Picture 1: Start with Portrait]
[image: Picture 2: Move to Landscape]
But when i start from landscape and switch to portrait the Image won't be scaled down and only the half is visible, which is also for the crop rectangle (See the last 2 Pics).

[image: Picture 3: Start from Landscape]
[image: Picture 4: Move to Portrait with Layout error].

There is only one XML Layout but a different behavior?

Heres my Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
        android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/times"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@null"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:onClick="cancelImageSelection"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@drawable/check"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@null"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:onClick="gimmeImageForPoll"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MY Manifest declares:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.CropperActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cropper"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
```

And finally my onCreate() of the Cropper Activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cropper);

        //dont show statusbar
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
        mCropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);


        Intent incomingData = getIntent();
        imageURI = Uri.parse(incomingData.getExtras().getString("imageURI"));
        mCropImageView.setImageUri(imageURI);
        //we need a quadrat for our PICs
        mCropImageView.setFixedAspectRatio(true);
        mCropImageView.setAspectRatio(1,1);
    }
```

Anyone got an idea, where this weird behavior comes from?

Comment: I finally solved it by handling in manually in the code. What you need to know is if the screen is in landscape or portrait and what format the picture is.